# I don't know why I keep on getting this error " syntax error near unexpected token `do' "

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, do-while

I don't understand why this isn't running. I looked up the syntax for while loops and I think I'm doing it right. Help, please.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

x=0 # init x=0
i=1
while[ $i -le $1 ] # while(i<=userInput)
do
        s=`expr $i \* $i` # s=i*i
        x=`expr $s + $x`
        i=`expr $i + 1` # i=i+1
done

echo x=$x
```

Comment: add space between ```while``` and ```[```

Comment: https://shellcheck.net bookmark it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between `while` and `[ $i -le $1 ]`.